# Implementing Queue Using single stack in java

Tags: java, data-structures, stack, queue

I'm trying to implement a queue using single stack using recursion. But I am struggling to implement the `deQueue()` method. This method has to return the first inserted element in the queue which is nothing but the last element in stack.

The below code is not working for me. Please correct it and share.

```
public String deQueue() {       
    return recursive();
}

public String recursive() {
    String result1 = null;
    String data;
    if (stack.empty()) {
         return null;
    }

    if (stack.count() ==1) {
        result1 = stack.pop();
        return result1;
    }

    data = stack.pop();
    recursive();
    stack.push(data);

    return result1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that you ignore the result of recursive().

```
...
data = stack.pop();
result1 = recursive();
stack.push(data);
...
```